# Switch between minified and un-minified javascript in flask?

Tags: javascript, flask

What's the best way to set up a flask app so that you can easily switch between:

- Human readable javascript source files.
- One minified source file generated with closure-compiler or somesuch.

The first thing I tried was to pass a list of source files as parameter to each of my calls to `render_template()`, then I put a for loop in `base.html` to include whatever files are specified.  But I have to pass this parameter every time I call render_template, and sometimes.... I'm not the one calling `render_template()`, because I'm using modules that call it for me.

What's the right way to do this?

Comment: Note: what you're calling "compiled" is, if I understand you, typically termed "minified".

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I have changed the wording of the question.

Comment: Have you looked into [Flask-Assets](https://flask-assets.readthedocs.org/en/latest/)?

Answer (score 0):

You can separate your development (human readable) and deployment (minified) files into distinct folders, as illustrated below:

```
source/
├─ static/
├─ static_dev/
├─ templates/
├─ templates_dev/
...
```

In your Python code, make your Flask app use the root URL as a static path:

```
app = Flask(__name__, static_url_path="")
```

You can switch between development and deployment folders based on your environment or global variable. That really depends on your system and your preferences, so the following code assumes that variable check is abstracted by a function:

```
if is_development_environment():
    app.static_folder   = "static_dev"
    app.template_folder = "templates_dev"
```

Finally, you need to instruct your minify scripts to pick source files from development folders and use deployment folders as output destination. Also make sure that only deployment folders are uploaded to your server, and that they are ignored by your source code control system.